# Replacing the capacitor on an old Philips amplifier

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, soldering, electrolytic-capacitor, replacement

My Philips amplifier broke down (model FA153) and my friend told me it's likely the capicators have worn out (they were produced in West Germany ;))

I am quite the layman in electrical engineering, but I am trying to replace the problem myself.

Current info on the capacitors:

[image]

It's the two 2553 and 2554 capacitors. With 6800 microfarad and 50V.  Diameter is 30mm and height is 50mm.

Here is a drawing of the circuit bord where the capacitors are:

[image]

It seems the positive contact point has 1 pin. There the capacitor is attached to a ring, which has three negative pins/contact points.

I was unable to remove the capacitor by soldering all contact points, so I forced the body off of the ring. Then I was able to remove the body by soldering the positive contact point. Result:

[image]

Currently, I am unsure how to proceed.

Is the ring part of the capacitor and should I remove it?

What would be a replacement capacitor?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:

extra picture of the other side of the PCB

[image]

Comment: I do have to wonder you started ripping out capacitors that are neither proven faulty nor proven OK, just because your friend said so. I mean, you would not jump off a cliff just because your friend says so either. The problem can be completely elsewhere, but now you must fix this before you can debug further if this even was a problem or not.

Comment: The friend (he is an electrical engineer) said so after running me through a small diagnostic test from a distance.
Basically what happened was as soon as I turned on the amplifier, a fast-paced clicking noise started from my speakers. The fact that the top of the capacitors was coming up and the fact that sliding the volume did not alter the clicking noise led him to strongly believe it was the capacitors.
Again, I never do this, but I wanted to learn, and of course you make makes. I did not have the tools to properly test. This is my first time soldering, so I am learning on the go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCB is made to accept multiple types of capacitors.

There are holes for these ring mounted capacitors of two different diameters.

And there are also holes for mounting standard radial capacitors.

Just buy new ones that fit to the standard radial cap holes. 6800uF, 50V.

Here, I edited squares to which holes are for standard capacitors. Red for positive, blue for negative.

[image: Caps1]
[image: Caps2]
[image: Caps3]

Comment: Thank you, as JRE pointed out in his answer, this might be difficult.

Comment: I don't understand. The PCB clearly has holes to mount a standard capacitor. After removing the metal ring, maybe cutting it into three separate pieces with wire cutters and desoldering them one at a time, you can mount a standard radial capacitor into the holes meant for standard radial capacitor.

Comment: The layout drawing clearly shows additional holes.  The photo of the board unfortunately shows **markings** but no additional holes.

Comment: @JRE So in the PCB photo, what do you think are the two circular things inside the metal ring, on the left and right to the small center hole? To me, they look like PCB holes, and there is solder visible.

Comment: To me, they look like markings on the surface of the board rather than holes.  Photos are tricky.  I suppose the only one who really knows if they are holes is wout konings, who physically has it to look at and poke.

Comment: I added an extra picture to the post of the other side of the PCB. 1 here is the positive pin of the capacitor I removed. 2 and 3 are the holes on the side of that hole, so the ones you are talking about. There are indeed soldering points on the other side of the board.
Point 4 and 5 are two of the three points where the ring is attached to.
So what you're saying I could use points 2 and 3 to solder a regular radial capitor to, and basically ignore holes 1, 4, and 5 (and the third negative point)?

Comment: The numbering does not make sense. I read your picture as point 2 was the original capacitor as it is desoldered, and the untouched solder point 3 are the same positive node. Untouched point 1 would be equal to the negative terminal. But yes, those two holes, on left and right of the desoldered terminal are the terminals for standard capacitor.

Comment: @woutkonings - Hi, You said: "*1 here is the positive pin of the capacitor I removed. 2 and 3 are the holes on the side of that hole*" (a) With respect, I don't agree about that numbering. Label **2** is clearly the empty hole in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzpXR.jpg), not 1 (on the reverse of capacitor position 2554). Please check and clarify. (b) You refer to labels 2 and 3 (really it's 1 and 3, as I just explained) as "holes". Are you *sure* they are *holes* there? Comments above suggest they may be just solder pads (no hole) in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HedoE.jpg).

Comment: You're both right. I messed up the numbering in my comment. As for the numbers 1 and 3, not sure what you mean. There are holes, with solder pads. 1 and 3 are the same as number 2.

Comment: @woutkonings Did you look at the pictures I edited with squares to indicate where to connect positive and negative terminals? If you buy standard capacitors, most likely the pins are too far apart to use the original positive terminal, and you should use the terminals I marked.

Answer (score 0):

The ring **was** part of the capacitor.

Regardless of its state before you started working, the capacitor is dead now and must be replaced.

You have to remove the ring before you install the new capacitor.  The ring is soldered to the negative traces on the PCB.

It has three pins.  You must heat them all at the same time and pull out the ring.

Alternatively, you melt the solder on one pin and use a small screwdriver to lever the ring up a millimeter or so.  Then you let the solder cool and harden.  Repeat for all three pins, and go around and around until you get the ring out.

---

Finding a proper replacement could be difficult.  Not that the value is unusual, but because the ring with three pins was there to hold that big sucker down.

You'll have trouble finding a part with those three pins.

Comment: Couldn't you leave the ring alone, and solder the negative terminal of the capacitor to the ring? Then, you wouldn't have to worry about the fact there are multiple negative terminals.

Comment: From the photo, there's just the plus pin and the ring.

Comment: Right, and the ring appears to connect all negative terminals together. So it would make sense to solder the replacement capacitor's negative terminal onto the ring (assuming your soldering iron is powerful enough) rather than removing the ring, soldering the positive terminal, *re-connecting the negative terminals with some wire*, and then soldering the negative terminal onto the wire (or in the same hole if it fits).

Comment: I'd remove the ring and find a proper replacement - preferably **with** the ring and three pins.  The ring and three pins were there to carry the weight of that very large capacitor.  Without them, you will have to mount the capacitor some way to keep it in place and not break its leads or pull out of the holes.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! Finding a replacement would be ideal, but I find it quite difficult to find one with the same values ánd the same construction (i.e. positivie pin in center and three negative pins at the side). If I cannot find anything, user253751's suggestions seems a valid option.

Comment: Excuse me, but only one of the three holes of the ring is electrically connected, and there are holes to mount a standard radial capacitor. See my answer. From the picture, it can take either large ring capacitor, smaller ring capacitor, or standard capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Note that only one of the two capacitor rings is connected to the system ground.  Also, of the two holes next to the center hole (top view), only one of them is connected electrically to the circuit.  This amplifier has bipolar power supplies, meaning that there are two poser supplies in series about ground, with one making + volts and the other making - volts.  The common connection between the two caps is ground.

So, you can replace the caps leaving the two rings in place, but be careful which of the remaining holes you use:

[image]

Top cap: + goes in upper hole; - goes in lower hole.

Bottom cap:  + goes in lower hole; - goes in upper hole.

Comment: Too small to suggest an edit, in the first paragraph: "poser supplies" -> "power supplies". Otherwise someone might think it is a term-of-art.

Comment: THAT is funny.  Consider it stolen.